# While running the flutter app with objectbox using android SDK id showing below error. Can anyone help me

Tags: android, flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox, flutter-pubspec

../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9440:26: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_cursor extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9453:23: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_box extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9461:5: Error: Type 'ffi.Bool' not found.
ffi.Bool Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> data, ffi.Size size,
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9461:35: Error: Type 'ffi.Uint8' not found.
ffi.Bool Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> data, ffi.Size size,
^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9461:23: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Bool Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> data, ffi.Size size,
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9461:52: Error: Type 'ffi.Size' not found.
ffi.Bool Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> data, ffi.Size size,
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9462:21: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9462:9: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9460:28: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
typedef obx_data_visitor = ffi.NativeFunction<
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9468:5: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(obx_err status, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9468:51: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(obx_err status, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9468:39: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Void Function(obx_err status, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9467:31: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
typedef obx_status_callback = ffi.NativeFunction<
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9470:25: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_async extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9472:33: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_query_builder extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9497:23: Error: Type 'ffi.Int' not found.
typedef obx_qb_cond = ffi.Int;
^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9499:25: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_query extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9501:30: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_query_prop extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9503:28: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_observer extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9510:5: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<obx_schema_id> type_ids,
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9510:23: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<obx_schema_id> type_ids,
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9511:9: Error: Type 'ffi.Size' not found.
ffi.Size type_ids_count, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9511:46: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Size type_ids_count, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9511:34: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Size type_ids_count, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9509:24: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
typedef obx_observer = ffi.NativeFunction<
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9515:26: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9515:56: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9515:44: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9515:7: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9544:32: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_tree_options extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9546:24: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_tree extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9548:31: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_tree_cursor extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9550:36: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_tree_leaves_info extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9559:5: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9560:48: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
obx_err status, obx_id id, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9560:36: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
obx_err status, obx_id id, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> user_data)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9558:39: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
typedef obx_tree_async_put_callback = ffi.NativeFunction<
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9562:30: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_weak_store extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9564:33: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_admin_options extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9566:25: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_admin extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9568:24: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_sync extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9628:31: Error: Type 'ffi.Struct' not found.
class OBX_sync_change extends ffi.Struct {
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9632:12: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
external ffi.Pointer<OBX_id_array> puts;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9634:12: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
external ffi.Pointer<OBX_id_array> removals;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9637:37: Error: Type 'ffi.Struct' not found.
class OBX_sync_change_array extends ffi.Struct {
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9638:12: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
external ffi.Pointer<OBX_sync_change> list;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9645:31: Error: Type 'ffi.Struct' not found.
class OBX_sync_object extends ffi.Struct {
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9654:24: Error: Type 'ffi.Uint8' not found.
external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> data;
^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9654:12: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> data;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9663:36: Error: Type 'ffi.Struct' not found.
class OBX_sync_msg_objects extends ffi.Struct {
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9664:24: Error: Type 'ffi.Uint8' not found.
external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> topic;
^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9664:12: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> topic;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9670:12: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
external ffi.Pointer<OBX_sync_object> objects;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9677:44: Error: Type 'ffi.Opaque' not found.
class OBX_sync_msg_objects_builder extends ffi.Opaque {}
^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9682:26: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9682:56: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9682:44: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9682:7: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9687:26: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9687:56: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9687:44: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9687:7: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9692:26: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9692:56: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9692:44: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9692:7: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9698:5: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Int32 code)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9698:35: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Int32 code)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9698:23: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Int32 code)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9698:50: Error: Type 'ffi.Int32' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Int32 code)>;
^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9697:43: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
typedef OBX_sync_listener_login_failure = ffi.NativeFunction<
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9703:26: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9703:56: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9703:44: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9703:7: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
= ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9708:5: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9709:21: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Pointer<OBX_sync_change_array> changes)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9709:9: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Pointer<OBX_sync_change_array> changes)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9709:36: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Pointer<OBX_sync_change_array> changes)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9707:36: Error: Type 'ffi.NativeFunction' not found.
typedef OBX_sync_listener_change = ffi.NativeFunction<
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9715:5: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Int64 timestamp_ns)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9715:35: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Int64 timestamp_ns)>;
^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9715:23: Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Int64 timestamp_ns)>;
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox-2.5.1/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox_c.dart:9715:50: Error: Type 'ffi.Int64' not found.
ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> arg, ffi.Int64 timestamp_ns)>;

Comment: You just dump an unformatted long error trace without explanation or code to reproduce the issue? Please check [ask] and [edit] your question.